# Is there a way to refer to methods of a class within a collection?

Tags: c++, qt, methods, function-pointers, class-members

I personally want this for Qt, so if the code is off, feel free to fix it.

What I want is to create a collection in which I can reference class members. I tried function pointers, but I get the error I can't use non-static members or something like that. I tried `&ClassName::memberName` but that gave me some error regarding how it had to be a constant or something.

I'm not sure what sort of code to provide since I'm trying to ask whether something is possible in c++ or not.

---

**Context**

Since people are probably going to ask why I would do this, I planned on having a long list of methods for various "tools" in my software. Each tool was associated with 4 mouse events: 1 for move, release, press, double click each.

I wanted to keep things efficient, so I was hoping to do something like

```cpp
enum class MouseAction { MOVE=-1, RELEASE, PRESS, DOUBLECLICK }
void mousePressed(MouseEvent *e) {mouseActionMethod[toolName][MouseAction::PRESS](e);}
```

For that, I needed a collection of the sort `map<Action, map<MouseAction, void*>>` where I would insert the class members into the `void*` as function pointers. However, doing that resulted in an error.

As explained previously, tried doing this in a few ways, and it's getting confusing. Would be better if I found out it's not possible before wasting any additional effort.

I also substituted the `void*` with `(ClassName*)` to try `&ClassName::methodName`, based on something I found on stack overflow for a different issue - to which the solution seemed like it didn't apply to me.

Comment: A non-static member function acts *with respect to an instance of the class.* I can play this cello or that cello, but I can't just "play the cello" without a cello. Do you intend that these functions operate with respect to instances of the class(es)? If so, then you must construct the function pointers with respect to those instances; if not, then you must use static member functions.

Comment: What I don't understand: A lot of `QWidget`s have mouse event handlers for a certain purpose. Overriding them would make those widgets unusable, at least, concerning interaction. This concerns aside... If you want to process e.g. mouse events for any widget of your appl., you may consider to install an event filter for your main window. [Qt doc. Event Filters](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters)

Comment: @Beta I see what you're saying, but I wouldn't be calling these methods until an instance has been created. I'm simply telling the software "look, when you have a guitar, this is how you play it when this happens" - and to do that itself, I shouldn't actually require a guitar, I don't think. I only need some way to reference "playing the guitar". In short, I just need to refer to the methods to easily access what to do depending on what tool I've selected.

Answer (score 2):

You might use function pointer for regular functions or static class methods:

```
void foo(int) {/**/}
struct S
{
    static void bar(int) {/**/}
};

// and then

main()
{
    void (*f1)(int) = &foo;
    void (*f2)(int) = &S::bar;

    f1(42); // calls foo(42)
    f2(42); // calls S::bar(42)
}
```

method pointers can be used for non static class methods

```
struct S
{
    void bar(int) {/**/}
};

// and then

main()
{
    void (S::*m)(int) = &S::bar;

    S s;

    (s.*m)(42); // call s.bar(42);
}
```

`std::function` is another alternative:

```
struct S
{
    void bar(int) {/**/}
};

// and then

main()
{
    std::function<void (S*, int)> f1 = &S::bar;
    S s;
    std::function<void (int)> f2 = [&s](int i) { s.bar(i); }
    std::function<void ()> f3 = [&s]() { s.bar(43); }

    f1(&s, 42);
    f2(42);
    f3();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`void *` is not a right type to hold function pointers.

Non-static member types in addition to their signature are bound to the class type too. In the following example pointer to `foo` is of type `void (A::*)(int)`. You can of course have a collection, `QMap` for example, to hold such pointers: `QMap<QString, void (A::*)(int)> collection;`

```
struct A {
    void foo(int a);
};
```

Also in order to make things simpler you can give a name to that type:

```
struct A {
    using MethodPointer = void (A::*)(int);
    void foo(int a);
};
```

and `QMap<QString, A::MethodPointer> collection;`.

---

However static member functions are just like normal functions:

```
struct A {
    static void foo(int a);
};
```

here pointer to `foo` is of type `void (*)(int)`.